# PostgreSQL citext extension not working

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a `citext` column on it. The `citext` extension is installed in a separate schema called `schema_extensions`.

But it's just not working. I've used this extension for many years, and in this one database it just isn't working.

I can do this:

```
select last_name from employees where last_name = 'Smith';
```

and it returns records. But when I do this:

```
select last_name from employees where last_name = 'smith';
```

it returns nothing.

Also, I have reindexed the table in question. Is there anything else I should be looking at?

Comment: Is `schema_extensions` in your search path?

Comment: It wasn't, but it is now. I did: ```ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET search_path = '$user','schema_extensions', 'public';```

Do I need to restart the database after a command like that? Do I need to reindex the table? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't need to restart, but you won't get the new search path until you reconnect. It's possible that the index may have been created incorrectly. If it was, I believe the index definition would say `(last_name)::text` instead of `last_name`.

Comment: I just can't figure it out. It's allowing the creation of the table containing the citext column with the ```citext``` extension having been created in the ```schema_extensions``` schema. This is really aggravating. I dropped the entire schema and recreated it even. Absolutely refuses to work. I am convinced that this is a bug.

Comment: This is how I created the extension: ```CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA shared_extensions;```

Comment: Does it work if you cast and qualify everything? i.e. `... WHERE last_name::schema_extensions.citext OPERATOR(schema_extensions.=) 'smith'::schema_extensions.citext`

Comment: Postgres will not use an extension created in a different schema. I was forced to put them in ```public```. I dropped all of the schema, recreated the extensions in ```public```, and then recreated my schemas and the queries work as they're supposed to now. It's pretty sad that the ```citext``` queries failed silently, that's a nasty bug.

Comment: It's definitely possible to put the extension in a separate schema; I've got about 800 databases here configured this way. [Here](http://pastebin.com/Cj1jrMNq) is a self-contained example, starting from a fresh database.

Comment: If the column was actually as `citext` type, `search_path` wouldn't cause this issue at all, the only effect of it would be that `\d` of the table would show the type with the schema, are you sure the column is `citext`? Care to show `\d` output? Or (if not in psql): `SELECT atttypid::regtype FROM pg_attribute WHERE attname='last_name' AND attrelid='employees'::regclass;`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue exactly and it was maddening. The solution is to ensure that whatever schema you installed `citext` into is on the `search_path`.

For example, if you installed `citext` into schema `my_schema`, then `my_schema` needs to be on the `search_path`.

To set the `search_path` globally on the DB forever, run:

`ALTER DATABASE my_db_name SET SEARCH_PATH TO path1, path2, my_schema;`

Be sure to use the correct DB name in that SQL and put your previously configured search path in there where I have `path1, path2`. Effectively, you want to *add* `my_schema` to the path and do not remove existing paths. To know your existing `search_path`, just run `show search_path`.

Also, this affects all *new* connections, and thus your current connection won't reflect the change. Simply reconnect and it will work. If you have any running services that have persistent DB connections, such as in a connection pool, you need to restart the service(s) so they will reconnect.